# Centos 7 diskless client cannot mount NFS

Tags: networking, centos, nfs, pxe

I've spent the last few days learning how to set up a diskless client in a couple virtualbox machines, following the guide in the [RHEL documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/ch-disklesssystems.html). So far I have made it through the whole guide, but I can't get the client's kernel to mount the NFS share to finish booting; the connection is always timing out. But my problem is that I can't figure out why.

Server:

- Centos 7.2
- Local IP 10.0.2.15
- NFS, DHCP, TFTP
- Firewall zone: trusted (allow all connections)
- SELinux: Permissive (allow all access)

Client:

- Local IP 10.0.2.20
- Kernel: Copy from server install
- File system: Copy of server install

Here are my configs for tftp, dhcp and nfs:

- tftp: http://www.pasteall.org/71049
- dhcp: http://www.pasteall.org/71044
- nfs exports: http://www.pasteall.org/71046
- hosts: http://www.pasteall.org/71048

Currently the error I get is `dracut-initqueue[258]: mount.nfs: Protocol not supported`

Previously I got `mount.nfs: Connection timed out`

What baffles me about the connection continually timing out is that I shouldn't have anything blocking network connections. The iPXE boot rom can obviously reach the server because it's receiving DHCP instructions and booting into initrd. The NFS server is running and unblocked by the firewall and SELinux. It seems to me the services are all pointing to the right location, the right permissions, the right IP. I can't seem to find what's blocking the connection. I would be grateful for any insight.

Ultimately I want to build a renderfarm with multiple physical machines booting diskless from the same nfs root. I don't have the hardware, but it should work identically in a couple VMs.

Comment: you didn't add here your asset PXE booting parameters; they include the nfs stuff.

Comment: Are you talking about how virtualbox boots from PXE? I have not configured the VB boot configs myself; they are default. If it's another config file on my server, which one is that? The parameters passed to the initrd/kernel through tftp (as far as I understand) have the nfs parameters. I'm fairly new to the larger world of networking and admin-ing, so please bear with me.

Comment: the booting kernel must have a line somewhere telling where the inird is located and also where is located the root fs to be (in your case) nfs mounted.